# Installing symfony with composer gives error

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, symfony

I have a arch linux droplet that I am trying to install symfony on. I got composer installed so I went to the directory I wanted the installation to go to and typed the `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ 2.4.2` command. Then I got this error. This confuses me because it says that even though its right there in the list. Can someone help me find out how to fix this issue?

I restarted httpd after the change as well.

```
[ErrorException]
  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/root/.composer/.htaccess) is not within the allowed p
  ath(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/:/usr/local/bin/:/root/.composer/.htacces
  s/)
```

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/680. Sounds like you're running `composer` as `root`. I strongly suggest you *don't* do that

Comment: @Phil well if I dont then i get the error `mkdir permission denied` so i need to be root or use sudo and both give the same error as in the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've *attempted* to add the right directory to the `open_basedir` allowed paths as I see `/root/.composer/.htaccess` in the list. The problem is, this list should only contain existing directories.

A quick fix would be to change that entry to simply `/root` as Composer will then attempt to create `.composer` and `.composer/.htaccess` in `/root`.

A better solution would be to grant your user permission to create the project in the desired directory so **you** can run `composer`.

Comment: how would i give permission. The user is a member of the wheel group which I enabled to use sudo.

Comment: @zachstarnes Just create the app directory first then run something like `sudo chown username /path/to/app/directory` then apply whatever permissions you need?

Comment: What if the path in the error message isn't found within the open_basedir?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you moved **composer.phar** to the bin/composer folder or not, anyway try creating a *Symfony* folder in *htdocs*; inside the folder create **composer.json** which contains [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/composer.json) ; now run this command in in terminal while you are redirected into the *Symfony* folder

```
php composer.phar install
```

If you have *composer.phar* in the same directory that command should work otherwise you need to use the full path of composer.phar in the top command